# Sharing "array of arrays" between two VHDL modules

Tags: arrays, module, vhdl

I have a problem of sharing an "array of arrays" between two VHDL modules.

I have declared an "array of arrays" in a VHDL sub-module as below,

```
type avg_log is array (0 to 31) of std_Logic_vector(19 downto 0); 
signal V1 :avg_log :=(others=>others=>'0');
```

I want to send all the elements of `V1()()` to the top module, I have tried with PORT & GENERIC, but I got an error message.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your `type` in a package, and then include it in both entities via `use` like this:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package p_avg is
    type avg_log is array (0 to 31) of std_Logic_vector(19 downto 0);
end package p_avg;
```

and then in your entity

```
use work.p_avg.all;
entity my_e is
    port(
      ...
      V1 : out avg_log := (others => (others => '0'));
      ...
    );
end entity;
```

and then use it in your port map in the surrounding architecture (where the package also has to be included)... There are other ways, but this is the way I would suggest...

Comment: I have tried as you mentioned, but I got error as "ERROR:HDLParsers:164  parse error, unexpected COLON, expecting IDENTIFIER or STRING_LITERAL" on port (V1 :out :avg_log :=(others=>others=>'0') ); on my top module, please help.

Comment: @karthik k, As shown in your error message, there was a spurious ':' between the out mode value and subtype indication avg_log.  MortenZdk's example below also shows a needed pair of parenthesis enclosing the right most others association in the the default value for the port output for the array of std_logic_vectors.  His sample code can actually be analyzed error free.  There's a message here about trusting (and using) pseudo code in answers.

Answer (score 0):

Entire example below, with definition of p_avg package (as BennyBarns suggested), my_e submodule my_e, and tb top module; can compile with ModelSim:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

package p_avg is
  type avg_log is array (0 to 31) of std_logic_vector(19 downto 0);
end package p_avg;



library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
library work;
use work.p_avg.all;

entity my_e is
  port(
    v1_o : out avg_log);
end entity;

architecture sim of my_e is
begin
  v1_o <= (others => (others => '0'));
end architecture;



library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
library work;
use work.p_avg.all;

entity tb is
end entity;

architecture sim of tb is
  signal v1 : avg_log;
begin

  my_e_1 : entity work.my_e
    port map(
      v1_o => v1);

end architecture;
```